# Replacing H1 strings

Tags: jquery

I want to replace a string in my H1 tag, that is I want to write "Hi, I am Udim Manny,' I design landing pages'/' I build websites'/ such that the the second quote replaces the  first quote in real time. For an example in case you don't understand, take a look at http://www.mattfarley.ca

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are looking for a typewriter style effect, this can be achieved easily using jquery.
This page explains exactly how to build one: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/typewriter-effect/

I have used that tutorial and borrowed a snippet to create the script below, which is a basic example of this. Like you requested, the quotes are typed out, then deleted and the next one is typed out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Demo</title>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
         var TxtType = function(el, toRotate, period) {
                this.toRotate = toRotate;
                this.el = el;
                this.loopNum = 0;
                this.period = parseInt(period, 10) || 2000;
                this.txt = '';
                this.tick();
                this.isDeleting = false;
            };

            TxtType.prototype.tick = function() {
                var i = this.loopNum % this.toRotate.length;
                var fullTxt = this.toRotate[i];

                if (this.isDeleting) {
                this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length - 1);
                } else {
                this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length + 1);
                }

                this.el.innerHTML = '<span class="wrap">'+this.txt+'</span>';

                var that = this;
                var delta = 200 - Math.random() * 100;

                if (this.isDeleting) { delta /= 2; }

                if (!this.isDeleting && this.txt === fullTxt) {
                delta = this.period;
                this.isDeleting = true;
                } else if (this.isDeleting && this.txt === '') {
                this.isDeleting = false;
                this.loopNum++;
                delta = 500;
                }

                setTimeout(function() {
                that.tick();
                }, delta);
            };

            window.onload = function() {
                var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('typewrite');
                for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
                    var toRotate = elements[i].getAttribute('data-type');
                    var period = elements[i].getAttribute('data-period');
                    if (toRotate) {
                      new TxtType(elements[i], JSON.parse(toRotate), period);
                    }
                }

            };   
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1> 
         Hi, I am Udim Manny,  
         <span class="typewrite" data-period="2000" data-type='[ "I design landing pages.", "I build websites." ]'>
         <span class="wrap"></span>
         </span>
      </h1>
   </body>
</html>
```